# Qual é a sequência de execuções para AsyncTask?

Tags: android, asynctask

Preciso sincronizar dados entre o servidor e a aplicação cliente no Android e para isso criei várias classes `ASyncTask`, uma sincroniza os Terceiros, as outras o Financeiro, Contas A Receber e Contas a Pagar, por exemplo.

Fiz isso para reaproveitamento de código, que será utilizado em outros serviços e activities.
Porém, no momento em que o usuário sincroniza a primeira vez, na `Activity` as `ASyncTask` são executadas uma abaixo da outra, sem verificação se a de cima finalizou a regra de negócio.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, quando uma `ASyncTask` é finalizada logo a de baixo é executada ou inicia-se antes mesmo das `ASyncTask` superiores encerrarem a execução?

O problema com isso é ocorrer inconsistência no banco de dados do Android quanto as foreign keys por exemplo na hora de salvar os registros no SQLite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode garantir que os *AsyncTask's* são executados em sequência usando o método [executeOnExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29) para executar cada um deles.

Esse método recebe como parâmetro o [Executor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) que irá executar as Task's, se passar o valor [AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#SERIAL_EXECUTOR) elas serão executadas de forma sequencial.

ex:

```
asyncTask1.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

// asyncTask2 só será executado após asyncTask1 ter terminado.
asyncTask2.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

**Edit:**

Tudo o que foi dito anteriormente é verdade mas esse é, a partir da versão **HONEYCOMB**, o modo como o método [execute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29) executa as *tasks*. Ou seja, não há necessidade de usar o método `executeOnExecutor()` se quiser que as *tasks* seja executadas em série.

Inicialmente, quando foram introduzidas, as *AsyncTasks* eram executadas em série, em uma única *thread*.
A partir da versão **DONUT** isso foi alterado para uma *pool de threads*, permitindo executar várias tarefas em paralelo.
O surgimento de vários problemas de compatibilidade, em que códigos antigos deixaram de funcionar correctamente, levaram que, a partir da versão **HONEYCOMB**, a execução passasse  a ser novamente em série.
Nessa altura foi introduzido o método `executeOnExecutor()` para permitir indicar explicitamente qual o modo de execução a adoptar.

Comment: Não conhecia este recurso, bem legal. Minha única ressalva é que o SERIAL_EXECUTOR é apenas um e as tarefas de banco de dados podem se ver serializadas com outras que não tèm relação lógica, se outra parte do programa usa o mesmo recurso. Eu preferiria ser explícito, fazendo cada passo agendar a próxima tarefa. Diminui a chance de uma mudança longe dali afetar o funcionamento.

Comment: @epx Não entendo o que quer dizer. Em termos práticos o `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` faz o mesmo que o que você propõe na sua resposta.

Comment: Vamos dizer que ele chame um método entre agendar a tarefa #1 e a tarefa #2. Aí esse método, que outra pessoa fez ou vai alterar, também usa o mesmo macete para executar um punhado de outras tarefas serializadas.

Answer (score 3):

Se você agendar um número de AsyncTask's, não há qualquer garantia de ordem de execução. Para garantir esta ordem você teria de agendar apenas a AsyncTask que deseja ver executada primeiro, e no onPostExecute() você agenda a segunda tarefa, e assim por diante.

Comment: E quanto ao método getStatus() não posso utilizar em conjunto com Status.FINISHED, Status.RUNNING por exemplo para verificar se a Thread foi finalizada? De qualquer modo gostei da forma como você me passou e já tinha pensado a respeito, queria ver se não teria uma maneira melhor. Obrigado pela sua resposta.