# Serviço permanente em background

Tags: java, android

Como correr um serviço permanente em background. Por exemplo eu quero que a minha app esteja sempre a correr este método :

```
           public void addToCalendar(){

    myDB = CustomApplication.getDatabaseHelper();
    ColorDrawable blue = new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE);
    for(int i=1;i <= myDB.getLastId();i++){
        String dt = myDB.getDates(i);
        java.text.SimpleDateFormat sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date teste = null;
        try {
            teste = sdf.parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        caldroidFragment.setBackgroundDrawableForDate(blue,teste);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer rodar em background, você vai precisar utilizar uma **AsyncTask**.

Dentro da AsyncTask tu coloca essa sua implementação.

E para rodar ela de tempo em tempo, tu pode utilizar um timer.

`final Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
       handler.post(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             new MinhaTask().execute(); //Dentro da Task tu coloca seu código
          }
        });
      }
};
timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000); //1000ms`

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Me ajudou mas como estar sempre a rodar em background deve ser dispendioso tenho uma duvida . Sabe como executar uma acção quando se muda de tab ? Ja pesquisei por isso mas aparece la um tal de TabHost que não sei o que é .

Comment: Não entendo a forma como está a fazer isso. Por que usar uma AsyncTask quando o Timer já executa o TimerTask em outra Thread?

Comment: @ramaral **Te aconselho a tentar por um código que execute bastante coisa, desta forma que tu pensou.** Mas pense o seguinte, a cada 1 segundo o TimerTask vai executar o run(), o que vai acontecer se sua tarefa não terminou de executar os comandos do run() que foram chamados anteriormente?

Comment: @PedroGouveia Se você está utilizando tabs no seu APP, acredito que tu tenha um "PageViewerAdapter", e como você quer executar uma ação ao mudar a tab, use ViewPager.onPageChangeListener no seu adapter.

Vou te deixar um link de um vídeo para ver se ajuda (criação de tabs):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00LLd7qr9sA,

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Você tem razão é por isso que um Timer só deve ser usado para executar tarefas curtas. No entanto o AsyncTask sofre do mesmo problema quando se usa o método `execute()`. Ambos, Timer e `AsyncTask.execute()` usam apenas uma thread, assim a tarefa seguinte só é iniciada quando a anterior terminar. O seu código só resolveria esse problema se usasse `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor()`, mas continuaria a ser uma "gambiarra".

Comment: @ramaral, mas se a cada chamada do run(), você chamar um "new AsyncTask().execute" , por exemplo, você tá criando uma outra thread, e não executando a anterior. Ou seja você vai criando várias threads independentes, e cada uma vai executar o seu "serviço". Mas aí tem que tomar cuidado, pra não executar muitas threads pesada, porque pode deixar o dispositivo lento ao rodar tantas threads pesadas em background. Tem que ser jogo rápido.

Comment: Está enganado, as AsyncTask, quando iniciadas por `execute()`, são todas executadas numa mesma Thread, veja a nota na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#execute%28Params...%29), ou veja a minha [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83856/2541) a [Sequência de execuções para AsyncTask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83831/2541).

Comment: @ramaral, entendi o que você quiz dizer, e tu está correto no seu ponto de vista. Mas, eu **estou me refirindo à interrupção da AsyncTask**, que pode ocorrer caso não tenha uma AsyncTask no método run() do timer, entende? (Que foi isso que você me perguntou, o porque de uma AsyncTask dentro de uma Thread) Com a AsyncTask no método run(), isso vai garantir que o código, que está dentro da AsyncTask, seja executado do início ao fim, sem interrupção. Independentemente de quantas AsyncTasks estiverem ali dentro do método run(), todas vão ser executar o que tiver que executar.

Comment: Não entendi o que quer dizer. A única razão que eu vejo para ter o código assim é para que a mesma tarefa seja iniciada, no tempo estipulado, mesmo que a anterior não tenha terminado. Se a ideia é essa eu substituía a AsyncTask por um Executor e usaria um Handler em vez do Timer. De qualquer forma é estranho querer executar **uma mesma** tarefa antes de terminar a anterior.